# CentOS 6.3 with kernel-ml(3.7.1-2.el6.elrepo.x86_64) - No Console Output

Tags: centos6, linux-kernel

I installed kernel-ml(3.7.1-2.el6.elrepo.x86_64) from elrepo on CentOS 6.3, and everything is working fine, except that I see nothing on the console and can't interact with it.

I can SSH to the machine, maybe it's some kernel parameter that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the kernel line in **/boot/grub/grub.conf**. If you have any **console** parameters set, make sure the first one is **console=tty0**.

The Linux kernel takes the first defined console as its primary console. If you have something like **console=ttyS0 console=tty0** then the kernel will be treating the serial port as the primary console.